# select count with clause where image

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have this query:

```
select COUNT(*)
from clienti_fizici 
where statut = '0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000001B0000001B0803000000BA0A04670000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000206348524D00007A26000080840000FA00000080E8000075300000EA6000003A98000017709CBA513C0000014A504C544500FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF00'
```

where the state is a `varbinary (max)` column from where it takes a particular picture, and I want to add ID where that image exists.

I don't know how to do it.

！[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjiGy.png)

So I have this table and I get 5 (green pictures) I want to count on the id where those green pictures appear, in the result is 5 ..

Comment: Post your schema, sample data and the desired result.

Comment: i edited my post with an example